# ASPXAUTH cookie not being set by WebSecurity.Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC4/EF5 project.  I've released a live copy which is working fine online, but on my development copy logging on is no longer working.  WebSecurity.Login is returning true and I've traced it through my custom membership provider's ValidateUser function, which is also returning true, but when I then check Controller.User.Identity.Name, it is an empty string!?

This was definitely not happening before.  I have made several changes to my model, including the user class which my custom membership provider uses.  I've also changed the transforms on the web.config for publishing, changed the database initialiser and set automatic migrations on, but I can't see how any of this stuff could be affecting it.  I could work back through all my changes and revert until it works, but I'd really rather avoid that if I can.  Hoping someone else can shed some light on it before I have to go that far?

EDIT: The ASPXAUTH cookie is not being set - I assume that this is the cause of the problem.  Not sure why that should be though

Answer (score 0):

Managed to pin it down - looks like the User.Identity.Name property hadn't updated after Login and I have some logic that automatically logs out invalid users